# python, nltk, multiple plotting result of word freqency(subplot)

Tags: python, plot, nltk, visualization

I'm trying to visualization most_common(10) words in each text. Here is my code.
(I used nltk.corpus.gutenberg all texts)

```
from nltk.corpus import gutenberg
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from nltk import ConditionalFreqDist
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
%matplotlib inline

stop_words = set(stopwords.words('English'))

cfd = ConditionalFreqDist((target[:-4], word.lower())
                         for target in gutenberg.fileids()
                         for word in gutenberg.words(target)
                         if word.lower() not in stop_words
                         and word.isalpha())

plt.figure(figsize = (10,10))
for i, title in enumerate(list(cfd.keys())):
    plt.subplot(6,3,i+1)
    cfd[title].plot(10)
```

I want to plot 6x3 using subplot but the result is always 18x1. Is there any good method about this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The way I was able to use subplot2grid was by substituting the plt.subplot() call with the subplot2grid call.  Here is how I was able to get it to work:

```
plt.figure(figsize = (6,3))
for i, title in enumerate(list(cfd.keys())):
    #     plt.subplot(6,3,i+1)
    plt.subplot2grid((6,3),(0,0), rowspan=10, colspan=10)
    cfd[title].plot(10, title=title)
```

Here is a general use for subplot2grid example:
    # Plot figure with subplots of different sizes
    fig = plt.figure(1)
    # set up subplot grid
    gridspec.GridSpec(3,3)

```
# large subplot
plt.subplot2grid((3,3), (0,0), colspan=2, rowspan=3)
```

Comment: It doesn't work. Maybe I don't know how to apply those function. Could you help me to solve this problem? Thanks.

Comment: I updated the answer to reflect the usage of the subplot2grid call instead of plt.subplot() call.  Let me know if that works for you, as this can make it easier when dealing with multiple subplots.